# PHP pseudo immutable object using clone

Tags: php, laravel, immutability

I wish to create a custom validator. But I don't want to call `new` everytime, as this makes it more difficult to test. I also think `App::make` is a tad ugly. I just want to Dependency Inject my custom validator and use it.

My thoughts on how to achieve this is by using `clone`. Calling the validate method, would set properties on the clone, rather than $this. So that way, the DI version of the class remains intact. It is also very easy to test / mock this way.

Is this an appropriate pattern / Should I just use `new`?

My custom validator

```
class CustomValidator
{
    protected $rules = [
        'key' => 'required',
    ];

    protected $errors = [];

    public function validate(array $event): CustomValidator
    {
        $v = Validator::make($event, $this->rules);

        if ($v->fails()) {
            $copy = clone $this;
            $copy->errors = $v->errors()->toArray();

            return $copy;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasErrors(): bool
    {
        return !empty($this->errors);
    }

    public function getErrors(): array
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    // customValidator is immutable. $v is cloned
    $v = $this->customValidator->validate($event);

    if ($v->hasErrors()) {
        // do something with $v->errors();
        continue;
    }

    // No errors... Do something else
}
```

Comment: Well, if `App::make` looks ugly, then Laravel is probably not the best choice. It is quite idiomatic way to use container, and the framework heavily relies on it. By default `bind` registers non-shared services, i.e. you get a fresh instance from container.

Comment: It's not just that `App::make` looks ugly. IMO - by using clone, it reduces the likelihood for errors. e.g. forgetting to `App:make` or forgetting to `new` would result in bugs in future iterations. e.g. by filling the `errors` array, and that artefact remaining in subsequent calls - even elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand how *forgetting* to `App::make` is worse than *forgetting* of `clone`, but it is really matter of taste in your case. Generally speaking, cloning is slightly different, since the clone shares the same instances of injected objects, which may or may not be a desired behaviour.

Comment: When you use the class, you would need to remember to `App::make(CustomValidator::class)` or `new CustomValidator` - rather than just using it.

When you clone within `Custom Validator`, you can just forget about the `App::make` and `new` as the Validator handles it itself

Comment: hmmm, I don't quite get an idea of  "*just using*" a class. You need to instantiate it somehow, unless it is a static one.

Comment: Ah, I get it. A typical XY problem. You just need to reset `$errors` on `validate`: first line in the `validate` method should be `$this->errors = [];`

Answer (score 0):

`clone` is totally valid and is often used for object immutability in fluent syntaxed APIs. So I see no problem there.

I suspect you'll get some comments regarding semi-immutability though, but I personally think it's a reasonable solution to your problem